# replace char at position using Emacs script

Tags: replace

Below script will insert a char at position:

```
#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script

(defun modify(filename)
  (find-file-literally filename)
  (goto-char 3)
  (insert "\x39")
  (save-buffer 0)
  (kill-buffer))

(modify "a.txt")
```

How can I modify it to replace a char at positon?
for example:

a.txt content is:

```
abcdefg
```

Output changed to:

```
ab9defg
```

Current script output is `ab9cdefg`.

Comment: Have you tried using `(delete-char 1)` before `insert`ing?

Comment: `insert` accepts chars as well as strings. You might find it clearer to write `(insert ?9)` or `(insert "9")` than to write `(insert "\x39")`.